# In Z3, what's the most efficient way to describe this in array theory?

Tags: arrays, z3

I want to describe the following problem using Z3.

```
int []array1=new int[100];
int []array2=new int[100];
array1[0~99]={i0, i1, ..., i99}; (i0...i99 > 0)
array2[0~99]={j0, j1, ..., j99}; (j0...j99 < 0)
int i, j; (0<=i<=99, 0<=j<=99)
does array1[i]==array2[j]?
```

This is unsatisfiable.

I use Z3 to describe this problem as follows:

```
(declare-const a1 (Array Int Int))
(declare-const a2 (Array Int Int))
(declare-const a1f (Array Int Int))
(declare-const a2f (Array Int Int))
(declare-const x0 Int)
....    
(declare-const x99 Int)
(assert (> x0 0))
....
(assert (> x99 0))
(declare-const y0 Int)
....    
(declare-const y99 Int)
(assert (< y0 0))
....
(assert (< y99 0))
(declare-const i1 Int)
(declare-const c1 Int)
(assert (<= i1 99))
(assert (>= i1 0))

(declare-const i2 Int)
(declare-const c2 Int)
(assert (<= i2 99))
(assert (>= i2 0))
(assert (= a1f (store (store (store (store (store (store (store (store ........ 95 x95) 96 x96) 97 x97) 98 x98) 99 x99)))
(assert (= a2f (store (store (store (store (store (store (store (store ........ 95 y95) 96 y96) 97 y97) 98 y98) 99 y99)))

(assert (= c1 (select a1f i1)))
(assert (= c2 (select a2f i2)))
(assert (= c1 c2))
(check-sat)
```

Is it right?
Is there other more efficient way to describe this by using the array theory?
I mean, a more efficient way requires less solving time for Z3.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For solving this problem, Z3 will use a Brute-force approach, it will essentially try all possible combinations. It will not manage to find the "smart" proof that we (as humans) immediately see.
On my machine, it takes approximately 17 secs for solving for arrays of size 100, 2.5 secs for arrays of size 50, and 0.1 secs for arrays of size 10.

However, if we encode the problem using quantifiers, it can instantaneously prove for any array size, we don't even need to specify a fixed array size. 
In this encoding, we say that for all `i` in `[0, N)`, `a1[i] > 0` and `a2[i] < 0`. Then, we say we want to find `j1` and `j2` in `[0, N)` s.t. `a1[j1] = a2[j2]`. Z3 will immediately return `unsat`. Here is the problem encoded using the Z3 Python API. [It is also available online at rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/kPslY).

```py
a1 = Array('a1', IntSort(), IntSort())
a2 = Array('a2', IntSort(), IntSort())
N  = Int('N')
i  = Int('i')
j1  = Int('j1')
j2  = Int('j2')
s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll(i, Implies(And(0 <= i, i < N), a1[i] > 0)))
s.add(ForAll(i, Implies(And(0 <= i, i < N), a2[i] < 0)))
s.add(0 <= j1, j1 < N)
s.add(0 <= j2, j2 < N)
s.add(a1[j1] == a2[j2])
print s
print s.check()
```

In the encoding above, we are using the quantifiers to summarize the information that Z3 could not figure out by itself in your encoding. The fact that for indices in `[0, N)` one array has only positive values, and the other one only negative values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also find that, if I don't use quantifier, it cost more than 100 seconds to find the answer for array of length 200. What if the property of the array elements can not be described using a formula with quantifiers? Then Z3 will use the brute force search, right?

Comment: I am using Z3 in basic symbolic execution. So I think I should use Z3 as a constraint solver, and I can not use the quantifiers in the formula, not as that in the Hoare style verification.  I wonder if I can use quantifiers in symbolic execution, maybe automatically or manually.